# Difference between $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(x+y(x)^2)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: calculus, notation

Is there any difference between $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2+y(x)^2\right)$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^2+y^2\right)$?

> $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2+y(x)^2\right) = 2x+2y(x)\dfrac{\partial y(x)}{\partial{x}}$$
>
> $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^2+y^2\right) = 2x+2y\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

Given that $y$ is a function of $x$, they both give a similar-looking answer, but are there any differences between the two?

Comment: Normally the $\partial$ symbol is used for partial derivatives only; in this case, $y$ is a function only of $x$, so we use the normal $d$ as it means the total derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2+y^2\right) = 2x\quad$ even if $y$ is function of other variables. For example, if $y=y(t,x,v,...)$ this changes nothing. The partial differentiation with respect to $x$ doesn't take account of what are the variables in $y$, which is the same as saying that it supposes $y=$constant, even if it isn't the case.

For the partial differentiation relatively to a variable , the other variables become non longer variables, but behave as parameters.

$\dfrac{d}{d x}\left(x^2+y^2\right) =\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2\right)+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(y^2\right) = 2x+2y\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}\quad$ : the total derivative takes account of that $y$ is non longer constant, but also function of $x$.

NOTE

In order to answer to the comment of Frank Vel :

This is a comment, but too long to be put in the comments section.

You are confused because you don't define without ambiguity the function of SEVERL VARIABLES that you want differentiate partially. So, you confuse $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ with $\frac{d}{d x}$

For example, writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+x)$ is a non sens if you want differentiate partially the function $f(x,y)=x+y$ with respect to $x$, even if $y=x^2$ or anything else.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y)=1$$
And  $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+y)=1$

On the other hand, if you don't want a partial derivative, but a total derivative this is different :
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x+y)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y)\right)+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x+y)\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=(1)+(1)\frac{dy}{dx}=(1)+(1)(2x)=1+2x$$
which is the same as $\frac{d}{dx}(x+x^2)=1+2x$

So, first you have to decide if you want a partial or a total derivative with respect to a variable.

Second, if you want a partial derivative, you have to clearly define a function with several variables. For example, do not write $f(x,y)=(x+x^2)$ which is a function with only one variable. Write $f(x,y)=(x+y)$ and $y=x^2$. This looks the same, but it is very different considering partial derivatives.

Of course, when one is familiar with partial derivation, it is allowed to simplify the writings and avoid all intermediate steps.

Comment: So if I say $y = x^2$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y+x) = 0+1$, even if $y = y(x)$? I'd've understood it if $y = y(t)$ or something, but since $y$ depends on $x$, can it really be treated as a constant? And isn't $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x^2+y^2) = 2x+2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \neq 2x+2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$?

Comment: See the NOTE added to my main answer.

Comment: To keep things simple: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$ denotes the partial derivative of function $f$ wrt. the first parameter, evaluated at $(x,y)$. The meaning of $x$ and $y$ in the context doesn't matter. This is why I quite often think this notation is unfortunate, it would make more sense to write something like $\partial_1$ to denote the partial derivative wrt. the first parameter. Motivated by this, I've even seen things like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, x^2)$ where the intended meaning is again "the partial derivative wrt. the first parameter, evaluated at $(x,x^2)$".

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ similarly to the total derivatve, e.g. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2+y^2)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 2x+2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$? This would let $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y) = 1+1\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 1+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2) = 1+2x$, otherwise it seems ill-defined, as $f(x,y(x))$ is still a function of one variable, $x$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ similarly to the total derivative ?  Certainly not : This would cause a lot of mistakes with confusions between $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,y)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y(x))$. You need to practice more complicated cases to realize  that. By the way, do you understand the pertinent comment of JiK ?

Comment: @Frank Vel. See a typical example of confusion between partial and total differentiation in : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964649/if-fx-y-0-prove-fracd2ydx2-fracf-xxf-y2-2f-xyf-xf-yf-yyf

Comment: So $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 4x$ could be anything, depending on what $f$ is? e.g. $f(y) = 4x$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 4x = 0$, or if $f(\color{red}{x},\color{green}{x}) = \color{red}{x}+3\color{green}{x} = 4x$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 4x = 1$, or $f(x) = 4x$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x) = 0$?

Comment: Again, you write non-sens. When do you will understand that writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as a sens only if you have defined a function of several variables in which $x$ is one of the variables. If you consider a function on only one variable, partial and total differential are the same, so you cannot understand the difference of meaning between them. Well, that's too much for me. Sorry, I will no longer answer to your comments. Best regards.